# Is there a free SLACK integration to mail a message?

Tags: email, integration, slack

Is there a free SLACK integration like MailClark, that is able to simply forward a SLACK message by email (SMTP)?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not aware of such plugins but you could develop a simple Node app that does it.

/email

Brings-up a modal where you can enter title & message. Or, if you wish to forward an existing message, you could add a message menu where it does the same functionality.

Comment: We've already implemented such a workaround (Nodemailer forwards content to an email address). But I was wondering if there is a way to send emails directly from SLACK.